# Facebook login URL just redirects to homepage

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have an application that opens this URL in a pop-up window (sensitive values removed).

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=my_key&cancel_url=my_url&display=popup&fbconnect=1&next=my_other_url&return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&req_perms=read_stream%2Cpublish_actions%2Cpublish_stream%2Coffline_access%2Cmanage_pages%2Cread_stream%2Cemail%2Cread_insights
```

It worked a couple of weeks ago. Now, if the user is logged in to FB, they are just redirected to the FB home page. If they are logged out, FB prompts for a login, but then they see a page that says there was an error with my application.

I'm not sure what changed to make this quit working.

Comment: Is the app in sandbox mode or disabled?

Comment: I just double-checked and the app is *not* in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old, non OAuth endpoints such as login.php were deprecated recently. If you are using the php sdk, you will have to upgrade to the newest version which supports OAuth. Otherwise, take a look at the web getting started guide for more info - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Comment: I was afraid of this. Ugh. Thanks!